# Installing MySQL 5.6 in Amazon Linux Machine

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services

I am trying to install MySQL 5.6 in amazon linux machine. by using following [link.](http://www.tocker.ca/2013/10/30/installing-the-latest-mysql-5.6-on-amazon-linux-using-official-repos.html)

after completing following steps.

```
sudo yum localinstall http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el6-3.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

when i am starting mysql services by this command.

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

I am getting MySQL Daemon failed to start error.

Comment: You should find an error log in /var/lib/mysql/{hostname}.err... see anything there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove old mySql

```
sudo yum remove mysql mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
```

remove all pre-installed packages. You can get a list:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
```

Then uninstall all of them. For example:

```
rpm -e mysql libmysqlclient15-5.0.94-0.2.4.1 <and so on>
```

Completely remove the /var/lib/mysql folder

```
    cd /var/lib
    rm -rf mysql
```

Installing fresh mySql 5.6 =>

```
    wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/MySQL-5.6.23-1.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar
    tar -xvf MySQL-5.6.23-1.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar
    sudo yum -y install MySQL-client-5.6.23-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
    sudo yum install MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.23-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
    sudo yum install MySQL-server-5.6.23-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: for a newer version we can follow the following :

mkdir mysql56-download ; cd  mysql56-download ;
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/MySQL-5.6.38-1.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar ;
tar -xvf MySQL-5.6.38-1.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar ;
# Remove old version #
yum remove mysql* ;

sudo yum -y install MySQL-client-5.6.38-1.el7.x86_64.rpm   MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.38-1.el7.x86_64.rpm  MySQL-server-5.6.38-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 7):

Starting from 2015 Sep, Mysql 5.6 server is now natively available through Amazon yum repos.  More info @ https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-available-amazon-linux-ami-2015-09/

You can now simply install Mysql 5.6 server using

```
sudo yum install mysql56-server
```

Then you can simply start/stop/status look using the regular service commands

```
service mysqld start ( restart | stop | status |  )
```

I couldn't figure out the default root password in Amazon AMI then I simply reset the root user password by starting the mysqld service with skip grant tables

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables start
mysql -u root 
update user set password=PASSWORD('[New Password]') where User='root';
```

OR

```
/usr/libexec/mysql56/mysqladmin -u root password 'new password'
```

Also,  you need to run the following command to upgrade the MySQL database to 5.6

```
sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem on my micro instance. Check your mysql logs
If the issue is because of 
InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool 
Adding a swap page might solve the problem. It solved for me.
You can follow this setup

## http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/05/amazon-ec2-linux-micro-swap-space.html

I copied the contents if the page does not loads

Amazon EC2 Micro Instance Swap Space - Linux
I have a Amazon EC2 Linux Micro instance. Since Micro instances have only 613MB of memory, MySQL crashed every now and then. After a long search about MySQL, Micro Instance and Memory Managment I found out there is no default SWAP space for Micro instance. So if you want to avoid the crash you may need to setup a swap space for your micro instance. Actually performance wise is better to enable swap.

Steps below show how to make a swap space for your Micro instance. I assume you have AWS Account with a Micro instance running.

Run dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=1024 
Run mkswap /swapfile
Run swapon /swapfile
Add this line /swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0 to /etc/fstab  
Step 4 is needed if you would like to automatically enable swap file after each reboot.

Some useful command related to SWAP space:
$ swapon -s   
$ free -k
$ swapoff -a
$ swapon  -a